# Code::Blocks: Jump to or Show Procedure Heading/Name

Tags: fortran, codeblocks, fortran90

I am using Code::Blocks as an IDE for Fortran. I'm looking at the code of a module that has quite a few subroutines that are all very long. Sometimes I would like to know what I'm subroutine I'm in, having jumped there from a search, for instance. I have tried using "Find" to locate the previous instance of "subroutine". But I find this to be quite clumsy and interferes with my current search. Is there a way to either show which function or subroutine I'm in, or to quickly jump to the subroutine or function heading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my (long untouched) installation of Code::Blocks I have a dock `Management`. In this dock go to the tab `FSymbols` and you will see the current module. Click on the module and you will see also the current procedure just below. See the screenshot, the current module and the current subroutine are **bold**:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you. I found that if you select `Current file's symbols` from the drop-down, it will show only the module you're looking at (no need to scroll to look for bold letters), and clicking on that, it will show you the procedures. Off-the-topic question: what is a "Symbol"? It seems CB means "modules", but aren't variables, procedures, and even operators (like "+") all symbols?

Comment: @user3786899 You are right, meaning of "symbol" can be quite general, normally it includes all variables and procedures. Probably not the intrinsic (built-in) operators, but the definition can vary. What they decide to display is solely the decision of the Code::Blocks developers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try noting your current line number, moving to the top of the file, and then collapsing subroutines until the line disappears.

For instance: subroutine *mysub* goes from lines 100-200. Say my search item was found at line 130. When I collapse *mysub*, the line numbers on the left side collapse down to 98, 99, 100, 201, 202, etc. So I know that my search item was in *mysub*.